# Assigning $.ajax to variables and passing to $.when

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

What i'm trying to achieve, is to make to AJAX requests, and when both are done update DOM with responses. The code goes as follows:

```
  var prefix = container.data("lang");

  var typeList = $.ajax({
    url: "/" + prefix + "/camps/list/",
    data: {
      url: hashLink
    },
    type: "POST"
  });

  var typeData = $.ajax({
    url: "/" + prefix + "/camps/type",
    data: {
      url: hashLink
    },
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON"
  });

  $.when(typeList, typeData).done(function(list, data) {
    console.log("we're done");
    //do something
  });
```

The problem goes as follows - i don't get any console logs at all. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Add a `.fail` handler (or better yet, switch to `.then(success,failure)` and see if it fails. Also, check the network tab and see if the requests both make it. Your code seems correct in general.

Comment: Deferred objects were introduced in jQuery 1.5.  What version of jQuery are you using?  Also, your Deferred usage looks ok, however, your ajax params look a little strange.  Do you have a parameter with the name "url" in your url?  For example ... "/ash/camps/list/?url=something.html"

Comment: Using `fail` handler i got my problem (typo in controller that corrupted my json output), thanks for the tip Benjamin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, error-checking with `fail` method is a very nice idea with jQuery async calls.
So, reworking my deferred like this:

```
$.when(typeList, typeData)
   .done(function(list, data) {
      console.log("we're done");
      //do something
   }).fail(function(list, data){
      console.log("Houston, we have a problem!");  
   });
```

Saved me a lot of trouble, and provided me with some error-handling to boot. Since we receive `statusText` as a parameter to our callback functions it is quite easy to get what's wrong.